# neo4j APOC apoc.convertToJson() cannot convert {"a" : "dddddd"}

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to add a property to a node using

```
 n.item = apoc.convert.toJson(itemObject)
```

Where

```
itemArrayObjects = {"source":"Blogspot.com","author":"noreply@blogger.com (Unknown)","title":"Elon Musk reveals who bitcoin's creator Satoshi Nakamoto might be","content":"Musk.MARK RALSTON/AFP via Getty Images\r\nElon Musk seems to agree with many that hyper-secret cryptocurrency expert Nick Szabo could be Satoshi Nakamoto, the mysterious creator of the digital currency… [+1467 chars]","publishedAt":"2021-12-29T20:41:00Z","url":"https://techncruncher.blogspot.com/2021/12/elon-musk-reveals-who-bitcoins-creator.html"}
```

this results in

```
Neo4jError: Failed to invoke function `apoc.convert.toJson`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In the Neo4j Browser this works:
RETURN apoc.convert.toJson({d:"ddddd", e:"eeee"})

but this doesn't work:

RETURN apoc.convert.toJson({"a": "aaaaaa", "b": "bbbbbb"})

If I assign the values to a cypher :param like this:

```
:param items =>[{source:"Blogspot.com",author:"noreply@blogger.com (Unknown)",title:"Elon Musk reveals who bitcoin's creator Satoshi Nakamoto might be",content:"Musk.MARK RALSTON/AFP via Getty Images\r\nElon Musk seems to agree with many that hyper-secret cryptocurrency expert Nick Szabo could be Satoshi Nakamoto, the mysterious creator of the digital currency… [+1467 chars]",publishedAt:"2021-12-29T20:41:00Z",url:"https://techncruncher.blogspot.com/2021/12/elon-musk-reveals-who-bitcoins-creator.html"},{d:"xxddddd",e:"eeee"},{d:"ddddd",e:"eeee"}]
```

I get this as :params

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "publishedAt": "2021-12-29T20:41:00Z",
      "author": "noreply@blogger.com (Unknown)",
      "source": "Blogspot.com",
      "title": "Elon Musk reveals who bitcoin's creator Satoshi Nakamoto might be",
      "url": "https://techncruncher.blogspot.com/2021/12/elon-musk-reveals-who-bitcoins-creator.html",
      "content": "Musk.MARK RALSTON/AFP via Getty Images
Elon Musk seems to agree with many that hyper-secret cryptocurrency expert Nick Szabo could be Satoshi Nakamoto, the mysterious creator of the digital currency… [+1467 chars]"
    },
    {
      "d": "xxddddd",
      "e": "eeee"
    },
    {
      "d": "ddddd",
      "e": "eeee"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the keys are double quoted "" as they rightly should
and this works:

return apoc.convert.toJson($items)

So it appears some behind the scenes conversions going on. It also appears to be some inconsistency as it works sometime without changes.

can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT: I am actually using neo4j Desktop 4.2.1 and APOC 4.2.0 locally and neo4j 4.4.2 docker image with apoc 4.4.0.1 on Digital Ocean. The inconsistency is that for the most part this works locally.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a bug in apoc v4.4.0.1 as it relates apoc.convert.Json()....a fix was made in v4.4.0.2